# Decidability of equality of expressions involving exponentiation

Tags: computability, closure-properties, number-theory, equality

Let's have expressions that are finite-sized trees, with elements of $\mathbb N$ as leaf nodes and the operations {$+,\times,-,/$, ^} with their usual semantics as the internal nodes, with the special note that we allow arbitrary expressions as the right-hand side of the exponentiation operation. Are the equality between such nodes (or, equivalently, comparison to zero) decidable? <s>Is the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)) under these operations a subset of algebraic numbers or not?</s> (Turns out, it isn't: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem, which disallows an easy reduction to solutions about algebraic numbers.)

This question is similar to this: [Decidability of Equality of Radical Expressions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/64392/decidability-of-equality-of-radical-expressions) but with the difference that here the exponentiation operator is symmetric in the type of the base and the exponent. That means that we could have exponents such as $3^\sqrt 2$. <s>It isn't clear to me, whether allowing exponentiation with irrationals retains the algebraic closure.</s>

This question is also similar to [Computability of equality to zero for a simple language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35969/computability-of-equality-to-zero-for-a-simple-language) but the answers to that question focused on the transcendental properties of combinations of $\pi$ and $e$, which I consider out of scope here.

Comment: What do you mean by "we allow arbitrary expressions as the right-hand side of the exponentiation operation"? What do you mean by "the closure under these operations"?

Comment: 1. I mean that the exponentation is not limited to expressions such as raising to integer powers (expression^2) or taking roots (expression^0.5) but we allow raising to powers of arbitrary expressions defined in the start of the paragraph.

Comment: How do you interpret $(-1)^{1/2}$?

Comment: 2. Closure under operation is explained in Wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics) It basically means that when I derive an object x using only the a set of allowed operators, I can use that object and the operators to derive more expressions; if there is a set of "all objects" that can be derived this way, that set forms a closure under those operators.

Comment: Here is your answer about closure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant.

Comment: On the other hand, under every reasonable interpretation (including multiple allowed values per exponentiation operation), the set of numbers produced by your expressions is countable.

Comment: Thanks, so it isn't algebraic. I asked that because if it turned out to be algebraic, I guess that the answer to the decidability part would have been an easy yes. Alas, that isn't the case, apparently.

Comment: About the interpretation, I thought about interpreting that as the "standard" imaginary unit, is there any other interesting interpretations?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_complex_numbers

Comment: How do you handle divisions by zero? What about exponentiations of zero?

Comment: For the purpose of this discussion, I thought of "just" disallowing division by zero, but now that you mention it, my original problem undermines the certainty whether that can be done. I guess that every "potential" division by zero still reduces to a simpler statement whether the denominator is zero or not, but if a^b and c^d (b and d being algebraic irrationals) are both transcendental, it might be impossible to say if a^b + c^d sums to zero or not...

Comment: You also still haven't responded about the issue of complex exponentiation. What is $i^i$, for example? You can choose a particular branch of the complex logarithm function for definiteness, but so far haven't indicated so.

Comment: It seems that this question isn't completely thought out. I suggest taking a few days to reflect on the question, and asking it again when all of these points have been addressed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I was unaware of many subtleties of exponentiation with complex numbers. I'll refine the question after reflecting on it a bit. Do you think I should close it for now and open new one(s) afterwards, or try to edit it?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks again for the clarifying questions. I posted a new question here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/125874/decidability-of-equality-and-soundness-of-expressions-involving-elementary-arit