# Algorithm to check two binary expression trees for equivalence

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Is there any known algorithm to check for equivalence of two binary expression trees over a field $\mathbb{F}$?

For example for the expression $a+b = b+a$ it should return true (since $\mathbb{F}$ is commutative) and $a^b = b^a$ should return false as well as for $a^2 = a$.

I can think of a naive implementation which is basically brute-force creating all equivalent binary expression trees for LHS and for RHS and check for a non empty intersection.

Is there a real-world-efficient algorithm to do this? I mean it isn't a must to be polynomial time but will work fast for common or relatively small problems (trees with at most ~100 nodes).

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) doesn't give any reference to the problem of comparing two for equivalence over some algebraic structure.

Comment: Is $\mathbb F$ some arbitrary fixed finite field? 1) $a^2 = a$ in $\mathbb F_2$. 2) You can express boolean formulas as polynomials, so your problem is at least NP-hard, by reduction from SAT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends heavily on what operations you allow to appear in the trees.

If the tree uses only addition, subtraction, and multiplication, this is an instance of the [polynomial identity testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_identity_testing) problem, which can be solved in polynomial time by a randomized algorithm.  Basically, you pick random values for $a,b$ and check whether both trees return the same value; and repeat a few hundred times.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma and [Is there an efficient algorithm for expression equivalence?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/33113/755).

Division can also be handled by expressing the tree as a rational polynomial (ratio of two polynomials), then again using polynomial identity testing.

If you can have addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and exponentiation, then I don't know whether there are efficient algorithms.  I think that problem, or some variant of it, is addressed here: [Decidability of equality, and soundness of expressions involving elementary arithmetic and exponentials](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/125874/755).

---

(Possibly loosely related: [Decidability of Equality of Radical Expressions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/64392/755.))

Let me also highlight that expressions like $a^b$ "smell fishy" and don't typecheck when $a,b \in \mathbb{F}$ are elements of a finite field.  For instance, if $\mathbb{F}=GF(p)$, then exponentiation $a^b$ is well-defined if $a$ is taken modulo $p$ and $b$ is taken modulo $p-1$ (not modulo $p$).  In particular, $(a+p)^b=a^b$ modulo $p$, but $a^{b+p} \ne a^b$ modulo $p$.  So, to make an expression like $a^b$ make sense, $a^b$ has to be interpreted as $a^{f(b)}$ where $f$ maps from elements of $GF(p)$ to numbers $\{0,1,\dots,p-2\}$.  There is a natural way to do that, e.g., $f(0)=0$, $f(1)=1$, ..., $f(p-2)=p-2$, $f(p-1)=0$.  But then when you do that, exponentiation doesn't have the properties you might expect.  In particular, $a^{b+c}$ is no longer equal to $a^b \times a^c$.  For instance, if $b=1$ and $c=p-1$, then $a^{b+c}=a^{p-1+1}=a^0=1$, but $a^b = a^1 = a$ and $a^c = a^{p-1} = 1$, so $a^{b+c}=1$ but $a^b \times a^c = a$.  So I would be pretty suspicious of any expression that contains exponentiation where the expression in the exponent is an element of $\mathbb{F}$.